# are there any benefits of using base64 instead of raw files (png, jpg, jpeg, gif)?

Tags: image, base64, jpeg, gif

I am creating an e-commerce website and I want to know whether it is good to store or handle the file(png, jpg, jpeg, gif) in base64 instead of raw file in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use raw image because base64 is 37% larger.